# fclose()/pclose() may block on some file pointers

Tags: c, unix, popen, stdio, fclose

Calling `fclose()` here after `dup()`ing its file descriptor blocks until the child process has ended (presumably because the stream has ended).

```
FILE *f = popen("./output", "r");
int d = dup(fileno(f));
fclose(f);
```

However by manually performing the `pipe()`, `fork()`, `execvp()` of the `popen()`, and then `dup()`ing the pipe's read file descriptor, closing the original does not block.

```
int p[2];
pipe(p);
switch (fork()) {
    case 0: {
        char *argv[] = {"./output", NULL};
        close(p[0]);
        dup2(p[1], 1);
        execvp(*argv, argv);
    }
    default: {
        close(p[1]);
        int d = dup(p[0]);
        close(p[0]);
    }
}
```

Why does this occur, and how can I close the `FILE *` returned from `popen()` and use a file descriptor in its place?

**Update:**

I'm aware that the documentation says to use `pclose()`, however `fclose()` blocks as well. Furthermore, I poked around in the glibc code, and `pclose()` just calls `fclose()`. The behaviour is the same, whether `fclose()` or `pclose()` is used.

Comment: You know why the only defined way to close the `FILE*` from `popen()` blocks.  Perhaps you can explain a bit more what part of your question remains unanswered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disappointed with the generality of the answers so far (I can [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM), tyvm), I've investigated this thoroughly, by stepping through and reading the [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) source.

In glibc `pclose()` directly calls `fclose()` with no additional effect, so the 2 calls are same. In fact you could use `pclose()` and `fclose()` interchangeably. I'm sure this is purely a coincidence in the evolved implementation, and the use of `pclose()` to close a `FILE *` returned from `popen()` is still recommended.

The magic is in `popen()`. `FILE *`s in glibc contain a jump table with pointers to appropriate functions to handle such calls as `fseek()`, `fread()`, and of relevance `fclose()`. When calling `popen()`, a different jump table used than the one used by `fopen()`. The `close` member in this jump table points to a special function `_IO_new_proc_close`, which calls `waitpid()` on the pid stored in the region pointed to by `FILE *`.

Here's the relevant call stack in my version of glibc, which I've annotated with notes about what is going on:

```
// linux waitpid system call interface
#0  0x00f9a422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00c38513 in __waitpid_nocancel () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6

// removes fp from a chain of proc files
// and waits for the process of the stored pid to terminate
#2  0x00bff248 in _IO_new_proc_close (fp=0x804b008) at iopopen.c:357

// flushes the stream and calls close in its jump table
#3  0x00c09ff3 in _IO_new_file_close_it (fp=0x804b008) at fileops.c:175

// destroys the FILEs buffers
#4  0x00bfd548 in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x804b008) at iofclose.c:62

// calls fclose
#5  0x00c017fd in __new_pclose (fp=0x804b008) at pclose.c:43

// calls pclose
#6  0x08048788 in main () at opener.c:34
```

So the short of it is, using `popen()`, the returned `FILE *` must not be closed, even if you `dup()` its file descriptor, because it will block until the child process terminates. Of course, after this you'll be left with a file descriptor to a pipe which will contain whatever the child process managed to write() to it before terminating.

By not `fread()`ing with the file pointer returned from `popen()`, the underlying pipe will not be touched, it's safe to use the file descriptor by `fileno()`, and finish up by calling `pclose()`.

Comment: I mentioned the array of code pointers above. It's not just glibc, it's been like that in every UNIX standard C library forever.

How bizarre, you can write an answer to your own question and accept it as the answer? Wow, instant karma for everyone.

Comment: If you knew this, you could have answered as much.

Answer (score 9):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

**The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by wait4().**

Since pclose() wants to return the exit status, it has to wait for the child to terminate and generate one. Since fclose() calls pclose(), the same applies to fclose() for you.

If you fork and exec and do the rest yourself, you don't end up calling pclose() (directly or indirectly), so there's no waiting at close time. Note however that unless your program is set to ignore SIGCHLD, your process won't terminate (instead it'll go zombie) until the child does. But at least your cost will run to exit first.

Comment: `pclose()` calls `fclose()`, not the other way around.

Comment: Regardless. In your case, both will end up causing the wait. Because as far as I know, in UNIX, FILE *'s actually point at arrays of function pointers. Apparently the function pointer in the close spot for your FILE * from popen() waits for the child to finish so it can get the return value.

Comment: +1 Why is this voted down?  It's correct, helpful, and to the point

Comment: I couldn't get past the incorrect order of calls, and wanted specifics about why both `pclose()` and `fclose()` blocked, not some text from the man page.

Answer (score 1):

The `FILE*` returned by `popen()` should be closed by `pclose()`, not by `fclose()`.  Then, the documentation for `pclose()` specifies:

> The pclose() function waits for the
>   associated process to terminate and
>   returns the exit status of the command
>   as returned by wait4().

So the waiting is one of the two things `pclose()` does, besides closing the file descriptor.  `close()` does just one thing: it closes the descriptor.

In response to your second question, I think you can use the descriptor returned by `fileno()`.  There's no need to `dup()` it.  After you're done with it, `pclose()` the original.

Comment: @Andomar: I'm aware that the documentation says to use pclose(), however **`fclose()` blocks as well**. Furthermore, I poked around in the libc code, and `pclose()` just calls `fclose()`.

Comment: @Anacrolix: Calling `fclose()` on a `FILE*` from `popen()` is undefined behavior.  Your libc can do anything it likes: blocking, printing an error message, or formatting your disk

Comment: @Andomar, I'm well aware of that. I'm using the `fclose()`/`pclose()` comparison to point out that the waiting behaviour seems to be peculiar to the `fclose()` call.