# Why does popen() only work once?

Tags: c, macos, popen

When I run the program below on my Mac (OS/X 10.6.4), I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Read 66 lines of output from /bin/ps
Read 0 lines of output from /bin/ps
Read 0 lines of output from /bin/ps
Read 0 lines of output from /bin/ps
Read 0 lines of output from /bin/ps
```

Why is it that popen() only reads data the first time I call it, and subsequent passes return no output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      FILE * psAux = popen("/bin/ps ax", "r");
      if (psAux)
      {
         char buf[1024];
         int c = 0;
         while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), psAux)) c++;
         printf("Read %i lines of output from /bin/ps\n", c);
         fclose(psAux);
      }
      else printf("Error, popen() failed!\n");

      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `pclose` instead of `fclose`. (Tested and verified.)

`fclose` isn't resetting the pipe state, since it is designed to close *files*, not *pipes*. `pclose` will properly close the pipe, so you can reopen it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736983/fclose-pclose-may-block-on-some-file-pointers/1769672#1769672) for an in depth reason as to why `fclose` and `pclose` differ and how.